# Change Font type and size for the whole JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jframe, jpanel

I am working on Java GUI project. I have several components on the swing-based GUI. I want to change the font settings for all the components, rather than changing font for each component one by one.

Is there a way to change the font type and size of all the components on a JPanel on a JFrame.

Edit:

This is how my code looks:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{
   public Test(){

     //all components are initialized here. (some buttons and text fields) and added to this
      this.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String []args){
     new Test();
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void setUIFont(javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource f)
{   
    java.util.Enumeration keys = UIManager.getDefaults().keys();
    while(keys.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        Object value = UIManager.get(key);
        if(value instanceof javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource) UIManager.put(key, f);
    }
}

// ...

try
{
    setUIFont(new javax.swing.plaf.FontUIResource("Tahoma",Font.PLAIN,12));
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

PS: I just copied this from old project of mine, and I am not sure from where I got it.

Comment: sorry for bothering. I have updated the my question with code. I am confused how to use the function you just suggested. I tried putting the function in `Test` class and calling it in the `Test()` constructor. But, it did not do anything.

Comment: It worked. Sorry I put the function at the end of all code, just before the visible thing. But, now it works when I put it at the top. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can set this `Font` into `UIManager`, but for every type of `JComponents` becase each of them have got own syntax in [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ListingUIDefaultProperties.htm)